# Python FTP Upload - Errorno -2, Name or service not known

Tags: python, ftp, raspberry-pi, ftplib

i am implementing a FTP upload with my python script. Everything works except for my ftp upload. I have used chmod to change the permissions of the folder that i have got my images and script in to chmod -R 777. And the permissions on the FTP server are all set at 777. Please note that ftpDir is intentionally left blank as this is the root folder for the account on the ftp server. I do not know what else i can do to fix this issue. 3

This is my error code that i get:

```
placeFile - Start FTP to ftp.brisbaneskycams.com
placeFile - ERROR FTP transfer Failed ...
  Filename : /home/pi/pimotion/images/capture-20160503-044806.jpg
  Error Msg: ['[Errno', '-2] Name or service not known']
  Please Investigate Problem ...
```

---

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#     Lightweight Motion Detection using python picamera libraries
#        based on code from raspberry pi forum by user utpalc
#        modified by Claude Pageau for this working example
#     ------------------------------------------------------------
# original code on github https://github.com/pageauc/picamera-motion

# This is sample code that can be used for further development

verbose = True
if verbose:
    print "Loading python libraries ....."
else:
    print "verbose output has been disabled verbose=False"

import picamera
import picamera.array
import datetime
import time
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from fractions import Fraction
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import os

#Constants
SECONDS2MICRO = 1000000  # Constant for converting Shutter Speed in Seconds to Microseconds

# User Customizable Settings
imageDir = "images"
imagePath = "/home/pi/pimotion/" + imageDir
imageNamePrefix = 'capture-'  # Prefix for all image file names. Eg front-
imageWidth = 1980
imageHeight = 1080
imageVFlip = False   # Flip image Vertically
imageHFlip = False   # Flip image Horizontally
imagePreview = False

# FTP Server location variables
ftpOn = True
ftpServer = "ftphostname"
ftpDir = ""
ftpUser = "ftpusername"
ftpPass = "XXXXXXXXXX"

numberSequence = False

threshold = 10  # How Much pixel changes
sensitivity = 100  # How many pixels change

nightISO = 800
nightShutSpeed = 6 * SECONDS2MICRO  # seconds times conversion to microseconds constant

# Advanced Settings not normally changed 
testWidth = 100
testHeight = 75

def checkImagePath(imagedir):
    # Find the path of this python script and set some global variables
    mypath=os.path.abspath(__file__)
    baseDir=mypath[0:mypath.rfind("/")+1]
    baseFileName=mypath[mypath.rfind("/")+1:mypath.rfind(".")]

    # Setup imagePath and create folder if it Does Not Exist.
    imagePath = baseDir + imagedir  # Where to save the images
    # if imagePath does not exist create the folder
    if not os.path.isdir(imagePath):
        if verbose:
            print "%s - Image Storage folder not found." % (progName)
            print "%s - Creating image storage folder %s " % (progName, imagePath)
        os.makedirs(imagePath)
    return imagePath

def takeDayImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, filename):
    if verbose:
        print "takeDayImage - Working ....."
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (imageWidth, imageHeight) 
        # camera.rotation = cameraRotate #Note use imageVFlip and imageHFlip variables
        if imagePreview:
            camera.start_preview()
        camera.vflip = imageVFlip
        camera.hflip = imageHFlip
        # Day Automatic Mode
        camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
        camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
        camera.capture(filename)

def placeFile(filepath):
    path, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    os.chdir(path) 
    print filename
    print path
    if verbose:
        print("placeFile - Start FTP to %s" % ftpServer )
    try:
        ftp = FTP(ftpServer)
        ftp.login(user=ftpUser, passwd = ftpPass)
        ftp.cwd(ftpDir)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
        ftp.quit()
        if verbose:  
            print("placeFile - SUCCESSFUL FTP Transfer")
            print("  Filename : %s " % (filepath))
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        errorcode_string = str(e).split(None, 1)
        if verbose:
            print("placeFile - ERROR FTP transfer Failed ...")
            print("  Filename : %s " % (filepath))
            print("  Error Msg: %s" % ( errorcode_string ))
            print("  Please Investigate Problem ...")


def takeNightImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, filename):
    if verbose:
        print "takeNightImage - Working ....."
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (imageWidth, imageHeight) 
        if imagePreview:
            camera.start_preview()
        camera.vflip = imageVFlip
        camera.hflip = imageHFlip
        # Night time low light settings have long exposure times 
        # Settings for Low Light Conditions 
        # Set a frame rate of 1/6 fps, then set shutter
        # speed to 6s and ISO to approx 800 per nightISO variable
        camera.framerate = Fraction(1, 6)
        camera.shutter_speed = nightShutSpeed
        camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
        camera.iso = nightISO
        # Give the camera a good long time to measure AWB
        # (you may wish to use fixed AWB instead)
        time.sleep(10)
        camera.capture(filename)
    if verbose:  
        print "checkNightMode - Captured %s" % (filename)
    return filename

def takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.resolution = (width, height)
        with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as stream:
            if daymode:
                camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
                camera.awb_mode = 'auto' 
            else:
                # Take Low Light image            
                # Set a framerate of 1/6 fps, then set shutter
                # speed to 6s and ISO to 800
                camera.framerate = Fraction(1, 6)
                camera.shutter_speed = nightShutSpeed
                camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
                camera.iso = nightISO
                # Give the camera a good long time to measure AWB
                # (you may wish to use fixed AWB instead)
                time.sleep( 10 )
            camera.capture(stream, format='rgb')
            return stream.array

def scanIfDay(width, height, daymode):
    data1 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
    while not motionFound:
        data2 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
        pCnt = 0L;
        diffCount = 0L;
        for w in range(0, width):
            for h in range(0, height):
                # get the diff of the pixel. Conversion to int
                # is required to avoid unsigned short overflow.
                diff = abs(int(data1[h][w][1]) - int(data2[h][w][1]))
                if  diff > threshold:
                    diffCount += 1
            if diffCount > sensitivity:
                break; #break outer loop.
        if diffCount > sensitivity:
            motionFound = True
        else:
            # print "Sum of all pixels=", pxCnt
            data2 = data1              
    return motionFound

def scanMotion(width, height, daymode):
    motionFound = False
    data1 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
    while not motionFound:
        data2 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
        diffCount = 0L;
        for w in range(0, width):
            for h in range(0, height):
                # get the diff of the pixel. Conversion to int
                # is required to avoid unsigned short overflow.
                diff = abs(int(data1[h][w][1]) - int(data2[h][w][1]))
                if  diff > threshold:
                    diffCount += 1
            if diffCount > sensitivity:
                break; #break outer loop.
        if diffCount > sensitivity:
            motionFound = True
        else:
            data2 = data1              
    return motionFound

def getFileName(imagePath, imageNamePrefix, currentCount):
    rightNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    if numberSequence :
        filename = imagePath + "/" + imageNamePrefix + str(currentCount) + ".jpg"
    else:
        filename = "%s/%s%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d.jpg" % ( imagePath, imageNamePrefix ,rightNow.year, rightNow.month, rightNow.day, rightNow.hour, rightNow.minute, rightNow.second)
    return filename    

def motionDetection():
    print "Scanning for Motion threshold=%i sensitivity=%i ......"  % (threshold, sensitivity)
    isDay = True
    currentCount= 1000
    while True:
        if scanMotion(testWidth, testHeight, isDay):
            filename = getFileName(imagePath, imageNamePrefix, currentCount)
            if numberSequence:
                currentCount += 1
            if isDay:
                takeDayImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
            else:
                takeNightImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
            if verbose:
                print("MotionDetection - Saved %s" % filename)
            if ftpOn:
                placeFile(filename)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        motionDetection()

    finally:
        print ""
        print "+++++++++++++++"
        print "Exiting Program"
        print "+++++++++++++++" 
        print ""
```

Comment: Which line does the error correspond to? This looks like a DNS error at this stage

Comment: This error occurrs when I run the script and it starts to upload the photo via ftp

Comment: So which line is that? The error messages taht you have included in the questions rae error messages that you have produced yourself. They are completely irrelevent .Get a stacktrace and see what the real error is and where it occurs.

Comment: What happens when you do `ping ftphostname` from the same machine you run the script on?

Comment: I did ping ftp.brisbaneskycams.com and it came up with
Z64 bytes from ns1.sgp2.siteground.asia (119.81.1.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=185 ms